# Как в PHP получить последний 1 или 2 символа с конца строки до согласной буквы

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Всем доброго дня!

У меня в файле несколько тысяч слов в строке. Задача заключается в том, чтобы получить окончания слов для составления парадигмы.

*Окончания для парадигмы 1: -а, -аа, -я, -ы, -ыы. Окончания для парадигмы 2: -е, -ээ, -и, -ии*

Вопрос: Как в PHP получить последний 1 или 2 символа с конца строки до согласной буквы? Думаю, что с помощью регулярных выражений можно сделать, но как правильно составить regex. Как вы считаете? Заранее благодарю за любой ваш ответ!

Comment: Т.е. надо получить две буквы последнего слова строки?

Comment: Лучше приведите примеры текста и ожидаемого результата, если есть ваши попытки - это плюс

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Как в PHP получить последний 1 или 2 символа с конца строки до
> согласной буквы?

Регулярное выражение:

```
(?<![аоуяёеыюиэ]|\b)[аояуёеыюиэ]{1,2}\b
```

Негативный просмотр назад, проверяем что нет гласной буквы или границы слова, после одна или две гласных буквы и граница слова.
Параметры регулярного выражения должны быть выставлены (`g` - global)¹ и `u` - unicode

---

UPD:

1. Спасибо [@Алексей Р](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/519463/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%A0) о предупреждении об отсутствии в PHP модификатора регулярного выражения `g`, исходя из этого следует использовать `preg_match_all`

---

```
/[![(?<!\[аоуяёеыюиэ\]|\b)\[аоуяёеыюиэ\]{1,2}\b][1]][1]/gu
```

---

В случае если граница слова не будет работать, то ее можно заменить негативными просмотрами:

`(?![\w-])` - Не захватывается, проверка что после не идет буквы, цифры, знака нижнего подчеркивания или тире
`(?<![\w-])` - Не захватывается, проверка что перед не идет буквы, цифры, знак нижнего подчеркивания или тире

Comment: 1. Модификатор `g` недоступен для [PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php), 
2. `\w` (=`[a-zA-Z0-9_]`) и `\b` не работают в общем случае с кириллицей

Comment: @АлексейР `\w` будет работать с модификатором unicode https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jme2.png. Сейчас посмотрел, вместо модификатора `g` нужно использовать `preg_match_all`, спасибо!

Comment: @АлексейР тут я ничего не выдумывал, в условии которое я процитировал, перед 1 или 2  гласными буквами должна идти согласная... по данной логике **длинношеее** не должно попадать в захват, поэтому и установил такое ограничение.